# Dynamic numbering of form field names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that duplicates the form like

```html
<form name="formularz[form1]"> 
  <input type="text" name="formularz[form1] [imie]" value="<?php code ?>"/> 
  <input type="text" name="formularz[form1][nazwisko]" value="<?php code ?>"/> 
</form>
```

I also have a problem, because after duplicating the "form" I would like to change it to `form2`, `form3`, `formN` in the next forms.

How can I do this in jQuery? I have not shown the code which duplicates form elements because it is not relevant.

Comment: how many form you want to duplicate ?

Comment: templating libraries like handlebarjs or mustachejs are more appropriate for this kind of thing.  or writing up your own short javascript method to do this.

Comment: Incremental attributes in HTTML is a really bad idea, not least because it causes a maintenance nightmare later on. Can you not just use arrays: `name="formularz[][imie]` then collate the fields on the server side by index?

Comment: @SupunPraneeth I want duplicate without limit

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var n = 100;//num forms you want

for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {

    var temp = '<form name="formularz[form' + i + ']"> \n' +
        '  <input type="text" name="formularz[form' + i + '] [imie]" value="<?php $code ?>"/> \n' +
        '  <input type="text" name="formularz[form' + i + '][nazwisko]" value="<?php $code ?>"/> \n' +
        '</form>';

    $('body').append(s);
}
```

Comment: your file is a `.js` file or `.php` file ?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. use foreach like this:

```
<?php foreach($data as $key => $row): ?>
<form name="formularz[form<?=$key?>]"> 
  <input type="text" name="formularz[form<?=$key?>] [imie]" value="<?php code ?>"/> 
  <input type="text" name="formularz[form<?=$key?>][nazwisko]" value="<?php code ?>"/> 
</form>
<?php endofreach; ?>
```